# Get FB statuses without using PHP

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I basically want to pull the text only from statuses I've written on facebook (no comments, likes, etc) for a website written in classic ASP. So it cannot be PHP coded.

It can be in ASP or just JS and HTML, ideally I'd like to spit out what's returned (top 10) in a loop, each status nested in a div, that way I can put them in one surrounding div using some jquery that shows one at a time, animating the transition.

Sounds so easy, Facebook's graph (v2) api seems reasonable but I'm just stuck as every example I can find is PHP based. I'm not sure where to start. I see from the API i'll need an access_token (should I create an App and use AppID|SecretID for permanency?) and I'll need my profile ID (no probs).

Can you offer a good starting point or example I can easily customise? I'd like to keep code to a minimum.

Comment: then first add `ASP` tag to your question..!

Comment: I was hoping ASP wouldn't be required at all - pure JS with HTML, but it *can* be ASP. Without ASP and PHP it can then be flexible.

Answer (score 2):

here a simple tutorial i used for a previous full javascript implementation 
http://codesamplez.com/development/access-facebook-graph-api-using-javascript-sdk
and here the official documentation :
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

Comment: Thanks for these - definitely the basis of what I was working on :-) I'd 'up' the answer as useful but I don't have a 15 reputation yet.

Answer (score 1):

It took some reading but here is the pure JS solution with no ASP or PHP. You need to go into FB developer section and create a blank app and make it active/live. You'll need the App ID, the App secret and you'll need your Facebook Page ID (found at the end of the URL of your Facebook page.

I only wanted to show posts I've made as page manager so I do an IF statement checking it's a 'shared_story' so i'm not showing others posts/comments etc.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
            $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_UK/all.js', function(){
                FB.init({ appId: 'Your_App_ID_Here' });
                FB.api(
                    "/Your_Page_ID_Here/posts?access_token=Your_App_ID_Here|Your_App_Secret_Here&limit=50",
                    function (response) {
                        if (response && !response.error) {                      
                            var $ul = $('#statuses');                       
                            for(i=0;i<response.data.length;i++) {
                                if(response.data[i].message && response.data[i].status_type != 'shared_story') {                                
                                    $ul.append($('<li>').html(response.data[i].message + '</li>'));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                );
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="statuses"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```